# Rs.exe fails to publish reports when SSL is disabled

Tags: ssl, reporting-services, tls1.2

I am using Rs.exe for automatic deployment of report files. When older versions of SSL and TLS are disabled , and **only TLS 1.2 is enabled**. Deployments are failing.
I am getting below error:

> Could not connect to server: https://ServerName/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx

Things I tried:
I added following registry entries as per
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc1cc0c5-65d0-48ac-a0b4-a689b9e6a2bd/2016-report-builder-connection-difficulty-with-tls-12-only-?forum=sqlreportingservices
Still no luck :(

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

OS -             Windows Server 2016
SQL -            SQL Server 2016
.NET framework - 4.7.1
Proper certificate is installed in server.
https://ServerName/reportserver is accessible in browser.
All valid configurations are done in RS Configuration Manager

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!